# Change background color of Button when clickable is false

Tags: android, button, view

I am attempting to change the color of my button via the selector when in the XML layout file the programmers specifies that the button is unclickable. ie. `android:clickable="false"` Here is my current selector xml file and it does not appear to work correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF00FF"/>
            <corners 
            android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
            android:topRightRadius="16dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="16dp"/>
        </shape> 
    </item>

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#CDAF95"/>
        <corners 
        android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:topRightRadius="16dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="16dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#D2B48C"/>
    <corners 
    android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
    android:topRightRadius="16dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="16dp"/>
```

Comment: Remove namespace attribute for  for shape tag...i.e remove this  `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no `state_clickable` attribute for `StateListDrawable`. You can solve the problem in two ways:

1. Change the background of the view, when `setClickable()` is called.
2. Introduce your own `state_clickable` selector state.

If you prefer the second way, you need to add the following changes to the project:

**attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ClickableState">
        <attr name="state_clickable" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**MyButton.java**

```
private static final int[] STATE_CLICKABLE = {R.attr.state_clickable};

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(final int extraSpace) {
    if (isClickable()) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_CLICKABLE);
        return drawableState;
    } else {
        return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
    }
}

@Override
public void setClickable(final boolean clickable) {
    super.setClickable(clickable);
    refreshDrawableState();
}
```

**background.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item auto:state_clickable="false">
        <!-- non-clickable shape here -->
    </item>

    <!-- other shapes -->
</selector>
```

But this solution has a very significant weakness. If you want to use this state in different view classes, you'll have to subclass these classes and add code from `MyButton.java` to them.

Comment: how do you know when setClickable has been called?

Comment: Do you mean the second solution? You override `setClickable()` method and that's how you now.